# Datagridview custom vscrollbar

Tags: c#, datagridview, c#-2.0

I would like disable vertical scroll bar in datagridview and managing the scrolling using separate vscroll control. I am using c# 2.0. Any one can help....????

Answer (score 1):

You can set DataGridView.ScrollBars property to ScrollBars.None or ScrollBars.Horizontal (to have just horizontal scrollbar). This way the vertical scrollbar will not be displayed and you can use yours

Comment: I got this idea.Do you know how can create my own vscrollbar which functioning as the datagrid scroll?